# Delete node without Confirm

Tags: 7, nodes

How to Delete nodes for specific Content type without redirect to a confirm delete page ?

```
function _node_delete_function($node) {
  if ($node->type == 'bills') {
    node_delete($node->nid);
    drupal_goto();
 }    
  else {
   
   return drupal_get_form('node_delete_confirm', $node);
  }
}
```

Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [hook_menu_alter()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_menu_alter/7.x).

Example :

```
/**
 * Implements hook_menu_alter().
 */
function Module_menu_alter(&$items) {
  $items['node/%node/delete']['page arguments'] = array('_custom_node_delete', 1);
}

/*
 * Custom delete.
 */
function _custom_node_delete($form, &$form_state, $node) {
  node_delete($node->nid);
  cache_clear_all();
  watchdog('content', '@type: deleted %title.', array('@type' => $node->type, '%title' => $node->title));
  drupal_set_message(
    t('@type %title has been deleted.', array('@type' => node_type_get_name($node), '%title' => $node->title))
  );
  $form_state['redirect'] = '<front>';
}
```

Comment: I can't save any new node with the code !!

Comment: I dont understand why you want save a new node.